# check directory in remote server while copy files from local to remote server unix

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

How to check whether directory exists or not in remotes server while copying files from local to remote server using ssh in linux.

If directory not exists it should create directory and copy files to that directory using scp.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the remote directory anyway, you could just call

```
ssh <server> mkdir -p <directory>
```

That will succeed if either *directory* has already existed or could have been created